Grid Image Recognition for Board Game
I want to create an automatic scoring app for a board game. The hard part of the app would be to turn this image into a data structure:

[
 [
  { name: "granary" },
  { name: "opposite the fireplace" },
  { name: "trumpet room" }
 ],
 [
  { name: "between two rooms" },
  { name: "throne room" }
 ]
]

From here I would be able to score the game no problem.
If anyone can get me started or point me in the right direction on how to tackle this that would be greatly appreciated! I'm good at javascript and java but open to any libraries/languages you think would be a good fit.

to find instances of known images in another image, feature matching + RANSAC for a homography model is a common approach. once you have that, you can figure out how they're positioned to each other. if you need that.

@ChristophRackwitz Thank you! great place to start :) I'll be looking into doing both in OpenCV with Java
